# Differential equations IVP and numercal methods question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

When we solving IVP analytically, it may happen, that we have several values of constants at the end. My question is: when we're using numerical methods, as Runge-Kutta, for example, they approximate only one sloution of IVP, i.e only with one of the constants, so why it's so, and can we change our numerical methods's parameters depending on constant?

Comment: Unless you're talking about problems without unique solutions, normally with a numerical method you just solve one IVP or BVP at a time.

Comment: @Ian but what exactly solution numerical methods approximate? In Euler and Runge-Kutta there is no dependecy on C, so when I'm plotting graphs, it approximate only one of the solutions

Comment: It's solving the IVP or BVP, not giving the general solution.

Comment: Do you realize that an IVP, an initial value problem, has in addition to the differential equation $y'=f(x,y)$ also an initial condition $y(x_0)=y_0$? This condition completely determines the parameters $C$, as said above.